# How to override column from Table A with JOIN mapping from Table B?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to **overlay** a column with another table, via `JOIN` mapping?

Table A:

```
int id;
varchar longname;
varchar type;
```

Table B:

```
varchar type;
varchar longname;
```

Sql:

```
select id, type, tableB.longname from tableA
   LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.type = tableB.type;
```

Result: `longname` is always `null` if there is no mapping in `tableB`.

Question: how could I retain `longname` from `tableA` if there is no mapping in tableB?

Comment: Look into `IFNULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, type, COALESCE(tableB.longname, tableA.longname) AS longname 
from tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.type = tableB.type;
```

Read about the [COALESCE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).